# Android Menu not Showing

Tags: android, button, layout, menu

I'd like to make a menu with a delete option. The actual delete functionality isn't made yet because at the moment I can't see the top bar in my app.

Main layout (activity_main.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="billy.cs436.placebadgesapp.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/newPlace"
        android:text="@string/newPlaceButton"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Menu layout (main.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/deleteMenu"
        android:icon="@drawable/clear"
        android:title="@string/deleteMenu"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />
</menu>
```

Main activity (MainActivity.java):

```
package billy.cs436.placebadgesapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button newPlace;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        newPlace = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newPlace);
        newPlace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), setLocation.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the main; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);//Menu Resource, Menu
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == R.id.deleteMenu) {
        // if there are no badges, toast message saying so (needs implementing)
            Toast.makeText(this, "There are no badges to delete!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //else clear all badges
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Badges cleared!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
```

Can anyone tell my why the New Place button is the only thing that shows up when this is run?

EDIT:
@T.S has the correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: What Style You Are Selecting in AndroidManifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your class to extend `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity`.